# Batch Starting Servers

Tags: server, bash, alias, functions

How I can create a batch alias for bash?

I need to do this:

```
cd /somefolder
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000
rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

`bundle` and `rackup` - this is 2 servers

for example I want bind `alias z=*all_of_this*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash functions are one method but I prefer to create separate scripts for things in my `~/bin/` directory:

```
mkdir ~/bin/
touch ~/bin/z
chmod +x ~/bin/z
gedit ~/bin/z
```

Then shove your script in there (with a header) so it looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd "$1"
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000
rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

Then just call `z <directory-path>`.

It *is* a longer method than an alias or a bash function but I prefer it because it's a little more separable than munging things in with your other aliases. I won't blame you if you don't agree!

Comment: You should aggressively quote stuff in bash, or you'll have many problems. It'd be better to write, `cd "$1"` or else you won't be able to pass in a directory path containing spaces or bash special characters.

Comment: Fair point and a trap I'm always falling into.

Comment: Because of that trap, my personal coding style is to treat "strings" and variables as strings in some other programming language where quotes are always required. I quote whether or not it's necessary to form the habit so I don't get caught out in situations where it matters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an alias; you want a bash function, which you can put in the same place as you put your aliases:

```
z() {
    cd "$1"   # This is the argument passed in
    bundle exec unicorn -p 3000
    rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
}
```

Call it like this:

```
z /somefolder
```